# Get the wall time in seconds using a linux command?

Tags: linux, time

How can I use a linux command to get the  wall time in seconds spent for executing a program. In the example below,I expected to get "0.005".

```
$ time ls >/dev/null

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.003s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your path:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e"
```

The normal time is given by bash's (if you happen to use bash) intern time command

```
type time
```

while you need the one,

```
which time
```

will find.

So in context of your command:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e" ls > /dev/null
```

But to store it in a variable, you can't use

```
a=$(/usr/bin/time -f "%e" ls > /dev/null)
```

because the output of time is written to the error stream, to not inflict with the programs output (in this example `ls`). See the manpage of `time` for further details.

An alternative to call a program, which is by default replaced by a bash builtin like time or echo, is, to precede it with the keyword `command`:

```
command time -f "%e" ls
```